# Highlight Column Headings

Tags: 2013, javascript

I am trying to highlight column headers in a list. I found this very simple script that I have added to the list in a script editor web part. The problem is I can see the highlight when saving but once the page refreshes the highlight is not there.

```
<style>

.ms-vh-div[DisplayName="Column1"]

{

background-color:#FFFF66;

}

.ms-vh-div[DisplayName="Column2"]

{

background-color:#FFFF66;

}

</style>
```

Is there is something missing from the script? Should I apply it a different way?

Answer (score 0):

your code works for me, try turning off the site feature called "Minimal Download Strategy". Also be sure to click apply / ok to save your web part, then click "Stop Editing" in the page ribbon to save the page.

Comment: I tried that but same thing. I have script in the web part for "sticky headers" and I have added the script for the column highlighting after that. Should I add another script editor web part and add the script there?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://sp./sites/SiteAssets/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://sp./sites/SiteAssets/StickyHeaders_3.1.1.js"></script>
<style>
 
.ms-vh-div[DisplayName="Initiative"]
 
{
 
background-color:#FFFF66;
 
}
 
.ms-vh-div[DisplayName="Jurisdiction"]
 
{
 
background-color:#FFFF66;
 
}
 
</style>

Comment: I used the Content Editor Web part and put the path to the .js file in that web part. Then I added the CSS in a Script Editor Web part separately. I noticed the color doesn't copy over to the sticky headers by default unless you define that in the sticky header.js file.

Comment: Is there a way to combine the two scripts so they both work?

Comment: Well the sticky headers script does its job when the header goes above the top of the window so that is when that style takes over. The script editor css is for when the sticky header code is not active. In my testing you can modify the style formatting in the stickeyheader.js file. (I looked for background-color and changed it from white to yellow. This makes the entire header yellow.

Comment: for what its worth I used this code for my script editor to make the entire header bar yellow instead of each heading.
<style>
.ms-viewheadertr
{
background-color:#FFFF66;
}
</style>